# mottie tablesorter 2.10.8, trigger custom filter function

Tags: tablesorter

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to trigger a customer filter function.  I have setup column ZERO to be filterable.  But I want to programmatically trigger the custom filter function because it filters based on other criteria (not just the text in the filter input field).  So a user doesn't have to enter text in the filter input field.  They can click on a check box, and I want that check box to trigger the custom filter function in tablesorter.

I've tried both:

`var filters = [];`
`filters[0] = '';`
`$.tablsorter.seFilters($('table'),filters,true));`

And I've tried this way as well:

`var columns = [];`
`columns[0] = '';`
`$('table').trigger('search', [columns]);`

Both ways don't work unless filters[0] has some data (ie. the filter input fields have some value).  I want to be able to trigger the custom filter function when there's nothing in the input filter fields)

Thanx in advance,
Leslie

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's just a typo, but the function is called `$.tablesorter.setFilters()`, and if you pass it an empty array, it will clear out the filters (reset). Here is a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/1045/):

HTML (excluding table)

```
<button data-search="1">1</button>
<button data-search="zyx">zyx</button>
<button data-search="">Clear</button>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter']
    });

    $('button').click(function () {
        var filter = $(this).attr('data-search');
        // only the first column filter is targetted
        $.tablesorter.setFilters($('table'), [filter], true);
    });
});
```

Change the `[filter]` to `[]` within the demo to prove it will work with empty arrays. You can even change `[filter]` to `''` (empty string) to reset the filters.

Also, in case you are interested, here is a [more elaborate demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/182/embedded/result/) with toggleable buttons from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440772/tablesorter-sort-multiple-checkboxes-multiple-columns/13514749).

Answer (score 0):

I found an example here of what I want:

```
// Add these options to the select dropdown (regex example)
    2 : {
      "A - D" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[A-D]/.test(e); },
      "E - H" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[E-H]/.test(e); },
      "I - L" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[I-L]/.test(e); },
      "M - P" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[M-P]/.test(e); },
      "Q - T" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[Q-T]/.test(e); },
      "U - X" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[U-X]/.test(e); },
      "Y - Z" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[Y-Z]/.test(e); }
    },
```

So essentially, I can add a filter dropdown to do custom filtering.  This means that my column can have a list of selection and each will perform it's own custom filtering to hide/show rows.  But what I need is for the text displayed in the list to be translated.  I use jquery i18n plugin to do translation.  It retrieves the translated string from the server like this:

```
var labelInText = i18nTranslateText('LABEL_IN');
var labelNearText = i18nTranslateText('LABEL_NEAR');
var labelOutOfText = i18nTranslateText('LABEL_OUTOF');
```

Then my filter function can be:

```
 2 : {
        labelInText      : function(e, n, f, i) { return n < 10; },
        labelNearText : function(e, n, f, i) { return n >= 10 && n <=100; },
        labelOutOfText     : function(e, n, f, i) { return n > 100; }
     }
```

But the drop-down ends up displaying "labelInText" instead of the translated text "Label In".

Do you know if there's an easy way for the drop-down list to show the translated text?